# Feeding a signal directly to an ADC or amplifying (active) it beforehand?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, instrumentation-amplifier, eeg

I am working on a project, where signals have the following characteristics (skip this if you are familiar with EEG):

1. amplitude in 10's or 100's of microvolts
2. frequency range: 1 to 100 Hz
3. Low SNR ratio

There is a open-hardware source for a device to measure these signals, called [openBCI](https://docs.openbci.com/docs/02Cyton/CytonSpecs), which adds to the signal path a TVS diode presumably for protection, and a passive RC LP filter, which from my understanding is there to attenuate high frequency noise because of the low SNR ratio of the signal (not really sure about this though), and then feeds it directly to an ADC. Note the ADC is specific for this purpose ([ADS1299](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1299.pdf?ts=1611249511725))

My question is this, would this design be improved (by a margin), when you:

1. add a DC blocking cap
2. Use an active amplifier for each signal, this includes amplifying the reference signal (which the In-Amps in the ADC use as the negative input). I think that although amplifying the signals prior to amplifying it against the reference signal would also amplify the noise, but the amplified reference signal would take care of that in the In-Amps in the ADC.

Am I correct in assuming that step 2 would not give rise to more noise, or is amplifying the signals reference taking away the reference signal from them rather useless? Thus why the openBCI designers designed it that way, or is it purely a cost/space problem?

Comment: *would this design* - if there is a baseline design you are referring to please add the schematic into the question because, without it, (1) and (2) cannot be addressed.

Comment: Do you think the internal amplifiers are not good enough for the task? If so, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Don't dink with it.  TI has a pretty good grasp of what they are doing.

Specifically:

1. Don't add a DC blocking capacitor.   The ADS1299 implements "Lead Off Detection"  (see section 9.3.2.4.3 in the datasheet) to tell you when the EEG leads are not making good contact.  That relies on DC coupling.  Your blocking capacitor would also block the lead off detection.
2. Don't add additional amplification.  The ADS2199 has programmable gain amplifiers built in - you'd be duplicating that function.  Amplification of microvolt level signals is harder than you expect - your additional amplification may well add more noise and offest than the benefits you (might) gain from more gain.
3. Don't add additional amplification. The amplifiers would interefere with the lead off detection.  The lead off detection would always "see" a good connection through the amplifiers - or maybe never "see" a good connection through the amplifiers.

The "ADC" isn't merely an ADC.  It is a system intended for a specific use, and includes functions beyond just converting analog signals to digital.  Unless you have  good grasp of what it is doing, it is unlikely that you'll be able to improve on it.  Even if you know what you are doing, implementing an improvement to the ADS1299 won't be trivial.